# Prestashop 1.7.6.8 (with not update) Impossible to login to backend

Tags: prestashop

Since yesterday and for no apparent reason I can't longer login to the backend of my prestashop 1.7.6.8.

The login page appears normal but if I insert credentials the button load for some seconds and after the page remains the login page. (If I insert wrong credentials the page remains the same except for the login fields that disappear).

- There was no updates (the version of prestashop is the same since I
  installed it and no modules have been added or updated these days).
- No changes have been made to the php 7.2 version of the server (and
  no change to other requirements)
- By activating the debug mode the backend login page does not show any
  errors I searched in the logs and there are no errors

What could be happened?

Thank you

Comment: Check the integrity of your PrestaShop installation overall. (No altered or installed rogue files); then check the integrity of the database.
It is off-topic here to ask help about a broken PrestaShop installation. StackOverflow is dedicated to specific programming questions.

Comment: Thank you Léa
I do not think that is a broken installation (no action were done in these days about prestashop files).

Comment: According to your description your shop had proably been hacked - Read here and check comments : https://build.prestashop.com/news/major-security-vulnerability-on-prestashop-websites/

Comment: Could you try to log into the incognito window?

Comment: @Sachin the problem was a iniection of malware in code as described here: https://build.prestashop-project.org/news/major-security-vulnerability-on-prestashop-websites/